# Summing up prices of user's cart from 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So, I have two arrays, one called `incart` and the other called `products`

The `incart` array contains objects (representing an item they have in the cart). Each object is composed of a product `id` and a product `qty`.

Moreover, the `products` array contains all the products on the website.
For example, inside the `products` array there are objects of each item. It contains a bunch of info about the product. The important one here is the product `price`.

In short, I need to sum up all the prices. The complicated thing is matching the individual product `qty` with the product `price` which are found in two arrays.

So my set up is as follows:
The products array represents all the items that the user has in their cart, which is being set by filtering through the `incart` array, this is being done to obtain the price of each product.

```
const {incart} = useContext(ContextApp)
const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

useEffect(()=> {

db.collection('products').doc('products').onSnapshot(snap=> {
  const productsdata = snap.data().products
  setProducts(productsdata.filter(x=> incart.some(el=> x.id === el.id)))
})
},[incart])
```

Any idea how I can relate these two arrays, maybe to compress them into another array which would in short only contain the price of the item and the qty of the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const incart = [{id: 1, qty: 1}, {id: 2, qty: 10}]
const products = [
  {id: 1, price: 1},
  {id: 2, price: 10}
]

const total = incart.reduce((acc, {id, qty}) => 
  acc + qty * products.find(x => x.id === id).price, 0)
console.log(total)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, how would i go about for doing it for one individual item?

Comment: this works for any number of items inside `incart`.

Comment: Yes, but just for one item. Like the total cost of one specific item, without summing them into a totla

Answer (score 2):

You're using the list of products as a lookup table, so I would use a Map instead of an array.

You also don't necessarily need to refetch all products from Firebase whenever the list of items in the cart changes, so I would store the product map in state, then calculate the total price in the body of the component.

As an aside, the `onSnapshot` method subscribes to changes in the document, so you either need to use `get()` instead, or you need to unsubscribe when the component unmounts. You can do this by returning the unsubscribe function from the body of the effect.

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const { incart } = useContext(ContextApp);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = db.collection("products")
      .doc("products")
      .onSnapshot((snap) => {
        const productsdata = snap.data().products;
        setProducts(
            new Map(productsdata.map(p => [p.id, p]))
        );
      });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const prices = products != null
    ? incart.map(p => products.get(p.id).price)
    : [];

  const totalPrice = prices.reduce((total, p) => total + p, 0);

  // ...
}
```